# Unable to open subtab in service console(Invalid Name error)

Tags: service-cloud-console, custom-console-components

All data is fine still facing invalid name error

```
sforce.console.openSubtab( resultInner2.id, 'www.salesforce.com', true, 'Close Case', subTabId,openSuccess, 'mysubtab');
```

> openSubTab: Invalid Name: mysubtab

I have tried all the option like
changing name, without this argument, empty string but still issue is same

Comment: What is the API you are using?

Comment: Beside below libraries I am using simple javascript which will be called when user will press special key(Defined in shortcut).

<head>
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/26.0/integration.js"/>
  <script src="/soap/ajax/26.0/connection.js" type="text/javascript"></script> 
</head>

Comment: Can you try without the last two arguments?

Comment: I already tried but it shows same error message : 'openSubTab: Invalid Name: undefined'.
If I remove subtabId it shows "duplicate tabs are not allowed"

Comment: I have solved this issue.. Thanks for the support. Actullay I have added sforce.console.addEventListener('CloseTab2', closeTabHandler2);  on component and inline visualforce page, So same tab was opening twice.